# UseSpaPrerendering being deprecated from .net core 3.0 onwards, what is the alternative?

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, server-side-rendering

`UseSpaPrerendering` being deprecated from .net core 3.0 onwards, what is the alternative for server-side rendering? 
How to migrate to .net core 3.0, If I'm using SSR in 2.1

There is no documentation on the future path on this. Microsoft doc says ***"Warning, This API is now obsolete."***

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.spaprerenderingextensions?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same issue, did you get any further with finding the alternative?

Comment: Same issue here, any news about the topic?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio but in their asp.net article they mention this way :(

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation is to rely on the SPA framework provided SSR capabilities. For Angular, SSR support is now integrated into Angular CLI. Here is a good article about it: https://medium.com/@MarkPieszak/angular-universal-server-side-rendering-deep-dive-dc442a6be7b7

Comment: imo it doesn't really cover that much related to .NET, just a reference to a github repo.

Comment: I don't understand this recommendation "...rely on the SPA framework provided SSR capabilities". Does this mean you no longer can achieve SSR for angular if you want your .NET 6 server to serve your angular app?